# Install iso ubuntu from USB

Tags: 14.04, usb, iso

I've downloaded the `.iso` file from Ubuntu's website.How can I use it to install Ubuntu?

I've searched a lot but every where the instructions are installing Ubuntu from windows.

Note: There's **No** OS in my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to burn the iso to a blanck CD/DVD or make a bootable USB, and then boot from this removable media to  install on your PC.

In general you need another PC to perform this action, or you can demand an Ubuntu DVD from some shops and use it.

In this [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) you can find different methods to perform that.

To make bootable usb using ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

To make bootable USB using Windows:http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Can you explain how to make a USB bootable?

Comment: @SLY Check the edit